# Rollup Summary Trigger Error: Invalid field xxxx for SObject Contact

Tags: apex, trigger, force.com

I have an Apex Trigger that is performing a Rollup from a custom object pse_Assignment__c to Contact. Below is the trigger that I have written and the error that I am receiving. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
trigger RollupActiveAssigmentLevelsToContact on pse__Assignment__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

set<Id> set_id = new set<Id>();

List<Contact> con_list = new List<Contact>();

if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
    for(pse__Assignment__c myAssignment : trigger.New) {
        set_id.add(myAssignment.pse__Resource__c);
    }
}
else if(trigger.isDelete){
    for(pse__Assignment__c myAssignment : trigger.Old){
        set_id.add(myAssignment.pse__Resource__c);
    }
}

if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isDelete)){
    con_list = [SELECT Id,Total_Levels__c, (SELECT Id,name FROM pse__Assignments__r WHERE Active_Assignment__c = TRUE) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :set_id];

    for(Contact con : con_list){
        if(con.pse_Assignments__r.size()>0)
            con.Total_Levels__c = con.pse_Assignments__r.size();
        else
            con.Total_Levels__c = 0;
    }
    if(!con_list.isEmpty())
    update con_list;
}
}
```

Error:

> Invalid field pse_assignments__r for SObject Contact

The error is on line 23 `con.Total_Levels__c = con.pse_Assignments__r.size();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier to perform an aggregate query. And always, I would be remiss to not mention that you would have an easier time implementing [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

```
public with sharing class AssignmentServices
{
    public static void updateContacts(List<pse__Assignment__c> assignments)
    {
        Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (pse__Assignment assignment : assignments) contactIds.add(assignment.Contact__c);
        setTotalLevels(contactIds);
    }
    public static void setTotalLevels(Set<Id> contactIds)
    {
        List<Contact> records = new List<Contact>();
        for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
            SELECT Contact__c, count(Id) records
            FROM pse__Assignment__c
            WHERE Active_Assignment__c = true
            GROUP BY Contact__c
        ]) records.add(generateRecord(aggregate));
        update records; // proper error handling advised
    }
    static Contact generateRecord(AggregateResult aggregate)
    {
        return new Contact(
            Id=(Id)aggregate.get('Contact__c'),
            Total_Levels__c=(Integer)aggregate.get('records');
        );
    }
}
```

Now in your trigger body, you can simply delegate the logic as necessary. I recommend looking into handler patterns, but that is outside the scope of this question.

```
trigger pseAssignment on pse__Assignment__c (/*events*/)
{
    if (trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert)
        {
            AssignmentServices.updateContacts(trigger.new);
        }
        if (trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            AssignmentServices.updateContacts(trigger.new);
        }
        if (trigger.isDelete)
        {
            AssignmentServices.updateContacts(trigger.old);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying to do this in replace of all my code?

Comment: You would just pass in `set_id` to this method. It would replace your query, loop, and update, yes. Also note, you do not need to check `isEmpty` before performing dml. It won't count as an operation if the list is empty.

Comment: Hmm I think it is misplaced in my code, because it says only top level class variables can be declared static. Can you modify your answer to have this class within my original code.

Comment: You should move your code to a separate class anyway. Keep logic out of the trigger body as much as possible.

Comment: Hmm I don't usually do this. I am fairly new to Apex. Only been doing it for about 6 months. How should I do this?

Comment: See updated answer. I can add the handler pattern I typically use if you're interested.

Comment: When creating the class it says Contact__c is an invalid field, but shouldn't that be an Object? Why does it think it is a field?

Comment: I just took a guess at the `API Name` of the `Lookup Relationship` field between the two objects. You'll have to change it to the actual name if I guessed incorrectly.

Comment: Would it be the API name of the field, or would it be the Child Relationship name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41879/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-cmmoutes13).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    trigger RollupActiveAssigmentLevelsToContact on pse__Assignment__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    set<Id> set_id = new set<Id>();

    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
        for(pse__Assignment__c myAssignment : trigger.New) {
            set_id.add(myAssignment.pse__Resource__c);
        }
    }
    else if(trigger.isDelete){
        for(pse__Assignment__c myAssignment : trigger.Old){
            set_id.add(myAssignment.pse__Resource__c);
        }
    }

    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isDelete)){
    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();

        for(Contact con : [SELECT Id,Total_Levels__c, (SELECT Id,name FROM pse__Assignments__r WHERE Active_Assignment__c = TRUE) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :set_id]) {
            con.Total_Levels__c = con.pse__Assignments__r.size() > 0 ? con.pse__Assignments__r.size() : 0 ;
            conList.add(con;)
        }

        if(!con_list.isEmpty()) update con_list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting the error: `Invalid type: pse_Assignments__c` on the line `for(pse_Assignment__c p : con.pse_Assignments__r){`

Comment: make the inner loop as `for(pse__Assignment__c p : con.pse__Assignments__r)`. Remove the 's'

Comment: Hmm it says Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [pse_Assignment__c].size()

Comment: let me correct that

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: please try now and let me know

Comment: I went with the other answer. Thank you for your answer though.